# How to write a query that joins same table in sql and compares the column values of one table with same column in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

**Write a query that checks for traffic inconsistencies.  An inconsistency is when a visit (url, uid, dt, src, rev) involves a source page src that was never visited by user uid. Return the key of the visit (url, uid, dt).**

This is the table I am working with:

**The primary key is url, uid, dt for the visit table.**

Visit:

| url | dt | uid | src | rev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A02 | 05/18/2003 | A | A05 | 20 |
| A03 | 05/19/2003 | B | A01 | 15 |
| A01 | 5/20/2004 | B | A02 | 10 |

**I would want it to return me these results:**

| url | dt | uid | src | rev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A02 | 05/18/2003 | A | A05 | 20 |
| A01 | 05/20/2004 | B | A02 | 10 |

This is because A05 which is the source of A02 was never visited by uid. A03 visit would not be returned because the source was visited by B before.

How would I write a query that returns this?

First, I did try connecting the two Visit tables together in a self Join on the src and url:

```
Select distinct V1.url, V1.uid
FROM Visit V1, Visit V2
WHERE V1.src = V2.url
```

But I am unsure where to go from here. I know that group by maybe be needed.

Comment: `A02` was never visited by uid `B`, why it is not in expected result

Comment: You are right! Sorry, I changed it

Comment: how about date constraint? `A01` was visited in year 2004, `A03` with src `A01` but was visited in year 2003, by common sense, it is not valid.

Comment: There is no date constraint, so even it doesn't make sense, it's fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NOT EXISTS` helps find these records.

```
SELECT *
FROM Visit a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM Visit b
  WHERE b.url = a.src 
  AND b.uid = a.uid
)
```